# Why is Windows 10 Sysprep removing some programs?

Tags: sysprep, kmplayer, windows-10-v20h2, windows-audit-mode

I’ve made a Sysprepped Windows 10 (20H2) but there is a problem with some installed software being removed.

I’ve installed KMPlayer (video and audio player) and Movavi Photo Editor (light weight photo editor) for our PCs in our company to edit photos before publishing them in Instagram and other social media out there.

After doing Sysprep with generalize option enabled this two programs were removed completely from Windows and only folder is remaining is KMPlayer folder in “Program Files” folder on the Windows drive.

Is there any way to Sysprep not remove those software items?

Other software like VLC, K-Lite Codecs, LibreOffice, Firefox, Chrome, 7zip and WinRAR with Free Download Manager remains but those 2 programs are not staying after Sysprep.

Comment: Are the programs installing to `%AppData%`/`%LocalAppData%`? If so, that's why - you can try to install them via `msiexec` to force installing to `%ProgramFiles%` if the installer doesn't allow that customization. [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--system-preparation--overview) may provide some help, depending on how familiar you are with `sysprep`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `PersistAllDeviceInstalls=true` in `unattend.xml` when syspreping.
If this doesn't help, perhaps the following text will explain why.

In general, Sysprep does not remove applications.
Some applications are sensitive to sysprep, but those are rare exceptions.

Sysprep strips out the machine-specific settings like activation ID and SID,
while leaving the installed programs for ease of deployment.
If certain applications rely on these machine-specific items,
they could break, which might be what's happening to your applications.